# Is there an English term that describes a comment on feedback?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I have the following form that requires the receiver to submit a comment on the feedback that they receive from the requester. I would like to know if there are any good English terms that describe this situation so that I can replace the words 'Receiver Comments on Feedback' with better ones. (I would prefer to use a single word.)

```
============================================================
| Requester Feedback:                                      |
============================================================
|                                                          |
|                                                          |
|                                                          |
|                                                          |
|                                                          |
|                                                          |
============================================================
| Receiver Comments on Feedback:                           |
============================================================
|                                                          |
|                                                          |
|                                                          |
|                                                          |
|                                                          |
|                                                          |
============================================================
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think "response" will do what you want. "Reply" or simply "comments" may also work.

Comment: So, do I just put "Receiver's response" or just the word "Response" will do?

Comment: "Reply" came to my mind as well.  "Response" works especially well if you think the additional comments may include a rebuttal.

Comment: @jack Since the feedback form is for the receiver, it's implied that the response is theirs (who else could be responding?) so yes, just response will do.

Comment: For what it's worth, I agree with Christi. In fact, "Receiver's Response" sounds a bit confusing.  (Who's the "Receiver"?  That could be anyone who views the form.)